Show count in each histplot bin
As explained in seaborn histplot - print y-values above each bar, counts can be displayed on each bar in a 1-d histogram by using .bar_label(ax.containers[0]).
I'm struggling to figure out how to do the equivalent for a 2-d histogram (created with sns.histplot(data, x='var1', y='var2')).
I know I can make an annotation for the (a,b) bin with .annotate('foo', xy=(a, b)), but I'm not sure how to retrieve the count for that bin (to pass it to .annotate()).
I'd like the result to look similar to the one shown at https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/spreadsheet_heatmap.html, except that it's a histplot, not a heatmap.

I found that the counts can be extracted from the histplot()'s .collections attribute and then .annotate()'d, as follows:
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.histplot(data, x='var1', y='var2', cbar=True)
w = ax.collections[0].get_coordinates().shape[1] - 1
for k, v in enumerate(ax.collections[0].get_array()):
    if not np.ma.is_masked(v):
        ax.annotate(v, xy=(k % w, k // w), ha='center', color='white')


Can you add some reproducible test data?  This doesn't seem to work with my test data.

To make your code work for categorical data with more than 1 x-value, you can change it to for k, v in enumerate(ax.collections[0].get_array().ravel()):  if not np.ma.is_masked(v):  ax.annotate(f'{v:.0f}', ...)

1. Working with np.histogram2d
You could make use of np.histogram2d() to do the counts, and then display the result via sns.heatmap():
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240529)
x = np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()
y = np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()

hist, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(x, y)
xlabels = [f'{x:.2f}' for x in (xbins[:-1] + xbins[1:]) / 2]
ylabels = [f'{y:.2f}' for y in (ybins[:-1] + ybins[1:]) / 2]
sns.heatmap(hist.T, xticklabels=xlabels, yticklabels=ylabels, annot=True, fmt='.0f', cbar=False)


2. Extracting information from sns.histplot
As mentioned in Peter's answer, the count and position information can also be extracted from the QuadMesh created by sns.histplot. Here is a generalization.
Calling .get_array() on the QuadMesh gives a masked array with the counts of each cell. It's a 2D matrix. The first row of that matrix are the counts of the first row (lowest y-value) in the plot.
Similarly, .get_coordinates() gives the positions. These aren't the positions of the centers of the cells, but their edges. There are 1 row and 1 column more edges than cells. The coordinates are organized as rows and columns of xy values (forming a 3d array).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240529)
x = np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()
y = np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()

ax = sns.histplot(x=x, y=y, bins=(10, 10), cbar=False)
coords = ax.collections[0].get_coordinates()
half_width = (coords[0, 1, 0] - coords[0, 0, 0]) / 2
half_height = (coords[1, 0, 1] - coords[0, 0, 1]) / 2
for v, (xv, yv) in zip(ax.collections[0].get_array().ravel(), coords[:-1, :-1, :].reshape(-1, 2)):
    if not np.ma.is_masked(v):
        ax.text(xv + half_width, yv + half_height, f'{v:.0f}', ha='center', va='center', color='white')


Here is how it would look like with categorical data:
sns.set_style('white')
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax = sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='who', y='class', cbar=False)
coords = ax.collections[0].get_coordinates()
half_width = (coords[0, 1, 0] - coords[0, 0, 0]) / 2
half_height = (coords[1, 0, 1] - coords[0, 0, 1]) / 2
for v, (xv, yv) in zip(ax.collections[0].get_array().ravel(), coords[:-1, :-1, :].reshape(-1, 2)):
    if not np.ma.is_masked(v):
        ax.text(xv + half_width, yv + half_height, f'{v:.0f}', ha='center', va='center', color='white')
ax.margins(x=0, y=0)  # remove unneeded whitespace
plt.tight_layout()



Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't think I can do a plain np.histogram2d as I have non-numeric values to count (i.e. non-numeric bin labels).
